# Hello world program gives an error on void in main

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have typed in the following code in Ubuntu using Emacs and compiled using the command line

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Having the void in the main function argument returns the following warning

```
helloworld.c: In function ‘main’:
helloworld.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

When I removed the "void" within the parenthesis the program compiled without any errors. What is incorrect in have `main(void)` in this program?

Compilation command is 
`gcc -Wall -ggdb helloworld.c -o hello`

Edit:
This is the screenshot which I would like to share
[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Please provide more information.

Comment: what kind of other information? I'm typing the code from a book _C for Linux Programming_ I'm pretty much new to C

Comment: The error output shows the closing brace on line 6, but your code has the closing brace on line 7. You would get *exactly* that error if the `return 0;` line was missing.

Comment: That code doesn't trigger this warning, please read my answer. Try to compile the code you posted is there a warning? No there is no warning because the code is *perfect*.

Comment: Save the file, then run the compiler again...

Comment: @Prasanna Did you *save* the file? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that warning could be for `main()` function is if you don't have a return statement *and* you are compiling in C89/C90 mode.

Since C99, a return statement at the end of `main()` is not required and it'll be assumed to `return 0;` if control returns from `main()`'s end. So compile in c99 or C11 mode:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -std=c11 helloworld.c -o hello
```

which won't trigger that warning. Or make sure you have `return` statement if you are compiling in c89/C90. Until recently (at least upto gcc 4.9), the default mode in gcc is `gnu90`. So you would get that warning withot a return statement if you don't pass`std=`.

I presume you don't actually have `return 0;` in your real code that produces this warning as it wouldn't matter in what mode of C you are compiling it if you had an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Your compile shell command compiled the program without warnings. What command should I use to find out the `std` and where can I read more about it?

Comment: You can find more info here: [Language Standards Supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html).

Comment: But before diving into standards, learn the correct workflow and how to read error messages. It's obvious, that you just haven't saved your file before compilation

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are probably right. But why the code compiled with warnings in the first place is the question now

Comment: Is it still having this warning? Please perform `cat helloworld.c` in the console and check if the code is identical to what you have posted.

Comment: @Prasanna That's because you are using a older gcc (without the return statement) that compiles code in gnu90, in which you need to provide an explicit return (otherwise, undefined). But that's no longer needed in C99 or C11. Hence, it disappears with `std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Comment: No. Not any more. But I still don't understand why I got the warning in the first place and then i introduce this `std` - it compiles without warnings. Back again I passed my `gcc...` command and now there no warnings. Surely there is something that I haven't captured

Comment: I am repeating in the third time - *you haven't saved your source file previously*. Now it is saved, so compiling without warnings.

Comment: I suspect the same, @EugeneSh. IF the OP disagrees, I suggest he use cat at the command line between compilations to prove what's on disk.  Screenshots of editors and terminal windows next to them do _not_ capture meaningful file content.

Answer (score 4):

The error doesn't have anything to do with the `void` in the signature of `main()` `int main(void)` is correct and is the way to define `main()` when you don't need to handle command line arguments.

The error means that you defined `int main(void)` and you did not return a value from the function. Like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");    
}
```

This warning was removed for `main()` in newer versions of *gcc* because `main()` implicitly returns `0` when the program exits unless you indicate otherwise with `exit()` or an explict return from `main()`.

Normal functions still trigger this warning and it helps in prevention of *undefined behavior* due to not returning from a function and trying to capture the return value.

Comment: Correction: `main()` implicitly returns `0` when control reaches its end without encountering a `return` statement. This happens *before* the programs exits.

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot in my question now to see if something is wrong